# encoding json to string

Tags: javascript, encryption, encoding

I'm interested how does google encode POST params.
In one of a application I've found the following approach, let say I have the following object:

```
selection={"ty":"mc","cl":{"loc_type":0,"si":9,"aps":false},"sr":[]}
```

In POST request it takes the following form:

```
 selection=%7B%22ty%22%3A%22mc%22%2C%22cl%22%3A%7B%22loc_type%22%3A0%2C%22si%22%3A9%2C%22aps%22%3Afalse%7D%2C%22sr%22%3A%5B%5D%7D
```

Which is method is applied here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same effect can be achieved by using `encodeURIComponent` and `JSON.stringify` functions:

```
"selection=" + encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(selection))
```

Answer (score 0):

It is called URL-Encoding.

It replaces non-ASCII characters and characters that have a special meaning in the URI scheme with a ASCII representation: Each character that isn't printable will be written as `%xy` where `xy` is the index inside the ASCII table of that character.

There are many programming languages supporting it out-of-the-box:

- In JavaScript you can use the encodeURIComponent() or encodeURI() function.

You can easily invoke it like this, e.g.:

```
var myjson = '{my:json}';
url_encoded_json = encodeURIComponent( myjson );
alert(url_encoded_json);
```

In other languages:

- PHP has the rawurlencode() function.
- ASP has the Server.URLEncode() function.
- Python has the urllib.urlencode() function.
- Java has the java.net.URI(url).toASCIIString() function

Answer (score 0):

It's simply URL encoding

Check out the built-in function encodeURIComponent(str) and encodeURI(str)

Answer (score 0):

the method in javascript is called `encodeURIComponent()` write

```
alert(encodeURIComponent('{"ty":"mc","cl":{"loc_type":0,"si":9,"aps":false},"sr":[]}'));
```